# sqlSave and sqlDrop in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

Here is my code:

```
library('RODBC')
db.handle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=server_name;database = db_name;trusted_connection=yes')
sql_table <- 'db_name.table_name'
sqlDrop(db.handle, sql_table, errors = TRUE)
sqlSave(db.handle,df_small,tablename = sql_table,safer=FALSE,append=TRUE,
        rownames = FALSE)
close(db.handle)
```

When I execute line:

```
sqlDrop(db.handle, sql_table, errors = TRUE)
```

I get error message:

> Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable, abort = errors) :
> ‘db_name.table_name’: table not found on channel

When I execute line:

```
sqlSave(db.handle,df_small,tablename = sql_table,safer=FALSE,append=TRUE,
            rownames = FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in sqlSave(db.handle, df_small, tablename = sql_table, safer =
> FALSE,  :  42S01 2714 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
> Server]
> There is already an object named 'table_name' in the database.
>
> [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect  'CREATE TABLE
> db_name.table_name  ("State_rename" varchar(255), "CoverageType"
> varchar(255))'

I execute code consecutively and cannot understand how both error messages can be true.

Answer (score 2):

Consider removing the schema from the *sqltable* variable which SQL Server uses with period qualifier. Specifically, change `db_name.table_name` to `table_name`. Reason you do not need this schema is your connection handle already specifies the database. With this connection, you cannot access other database schemas in specified server.

```
library('RODBC')

db.handle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};',
                               'server=server_name;database=db_name;trusted_connection=yes'))

sql_table <- 'table_name'
sqlDrop(db.handle, sql_table, errors = TRUE)
sqlSave(db.handle, df_small, tablename = sql_table, safer = FALSE,
        append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
close(db.handle)
```

By the way, you can simply use `append=FALSE` which will overwrite table (first dropping it and then re-creating it) with no need to call `sqlDrop`:

```
sqlSave(db.handle, df_small, tablename = sql_table, safer = FALSE,
        append = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Now `sqlDrop` generates error `Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable, abort = errors) : 
  ‘table_name’: table not found on channel` and sqlSave generates error `Error in sqlSave(db.handle, df_small, tablename = sql_table, safer = FALSE,  : 
  42000 262 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE table_name  ("State_rename" varchar(255), "CoverageType" varchar(255))'`

Comment: Hmmmm...what is the true name of *table*? It might be a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). Can you confirm database table in Management Studio or other console? And you might have DB permission issue.